# Geometric interpretation of the skew-symmetry of a matrix product $AB$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, and skew-symmetric ('schiefsymmetrische') property of square matrix $C$ given by formula $C^\intercal = -C$, I look for either some literature reference or explanation for property relating matrices $A$ and $B$ such that product $AB$ is skew-symmetric.

Thanks in advance!